# Why can't subscribe the request in reactor-netty?

Tags: reactor, reactor-netty

I just want access the Http content in reactor-netty project. But the result is **null**.

**Code is below.**

```
DisposableServer server =
            HttpServer.create()
                    .host("localhost")
                    .port(8000)
                    .route(routes ->
                                    .post("/echo",
                                            (request, response) -> 
                                                {   request.receive()
                                                        .retain()
                                                        .aggregate()
                                                        .asString()
                                                        .subscribe(System.out::println);
                                                    return response.sendString(Mono.just("hello"));})          
                    .bindNow();
```

I can't get the rerult in the console.

Could I access the request as what I do in the code?
Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return the response before the request data is received, so Reactor Netty will drop any incoming data that is received AFTER the response is sent.

I don't know your use case but changing the example to this below, you will be able to see the incoming data:

```
DisposableServer server =
        HttpServer.create()
                .host("localhost")
                .port(8000)
                .route(routes ->
                        routes.post("/echo",
                                (request, response) ->
                                        response.sendString(request.receive()
                                                .retain()
                                                .aggregate()
                                                .asString()
                                                .flatMap(s -> {
                                                    System.out.println(s);
                                                    return Mono.just("hello");
                                                })))
                )
                .bindNow();
```

Comment: Thanks.Maybe my reactor programmming base is so wesk.I will try hardly to study more about this topic.